# Rstudio does not start "Unable to determine real path of R script" due to previous error during compilation of R

Tags: r, rstudio, fedora

I am using Fedora 32, I have R (3.5.1 ) within conda. I also compiled R 4.0.0 from source but since I was having another problem with Rstudio I removed this version trying to solve these issues. (With 4.0.0 I couldn't install packages because I got an 'C++11 standard requested but CXX11 is not defined' error, I made the mistake of using --with-x=no during that compiling)

Now I tried to either compile a new version (4.0.1) or get R through yum, but every time I try to reinstall Rstudio I get this error:

```
Unable to determine real path of R script /home/andrespara/R-4.0.0/bin/R (system error 2 (Folder doesn'exist*))
```

I removed ~/.config/rstudio ~/.local/share/rstudio ~/.rstudio/ every time I removed/reinstalled Rstudio. I also searched for help in the rstudio community forums. I also

I compiled 4.0.1 with this line (deactivating conda before this avoided the X11 error that I had before)

```
./configure \                                                                                                                                                           
    --prefix=/opt/R/${R_VERSION} \
    --enable-memory-profiling \
    --enable-R-shlib \
    --with-blas \
    --with-lapack
```

I added symbolic links following these instructions https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r-source/

```
sudo ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R /usr/local/bin/R
sudo ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/Rscript /usr/local/bin/Rscript
```

R 4.0.1 is now correctly installed, I even used it today and installed some package the only missing link is with Rstudio and its installation that doesn't recognize it.

My question is how to either jump to another version of R working with Rstudio and get rid of that message when Rstudio starts.

- I should add can't even start Rstudio because it still asks for the 'broken version' even when I tried to reinstall it several times.

Comment: In RStudio, when you click on Tools -> Global Options, you'll see the R version you have. If you click on "Change" what versions are available?

Comment: @Phil I can't even start Rstudio because it still asks for the 'broken version' a small pop up window says " Unable to determine real path of R script /home/andrespara/R-4.0.0/bin/R (system error 2 (Folder doesn'exist*))" and nothing can be done. I tried clean and reinstall several times.

Comment: I run on the same problem, when I decided to start coding in python from RStudio. RStudio reassigned path to R (so it now uses the one from minconda3), then after I have upgraded R , Rstudio collapse - I can't now restart Rstudio. How do I `run RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=$(which R)' ?

Comment: @IVIM you run all this in the terminal  'conda deactivate ;  
RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=$(which R) ;
rstudio '  in the terminal see the edited answer below

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this thanks to a colleague who found a workaround.

First running `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=$(which R)` and then `rstudio` in the console bypassed the first error.

```
conda deactivate  
RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=$(which R)                                                                                                                                                            
rstudio
```

Then knowing the launcher was the error and thanks to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/112259/265501 I went to `/usr/share/applications`
and edited the line pointing to the useless binary with the correct one in the **rstudio.desktop** file found there.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, greatly helped me for the first part. I'm quite new to Ubuntu and unable to understand the second part, how do you edit the line pointing to the useless binary?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file  `~/.profile`

```
export RSTUDIO_WHICH_R=$(which R)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've created a symlink from the wrong location. Rstudio launcher is looking for R in /home/andrespara/R-4.0.0/bin/R but it can't find it there. Your symlinks should be redirecting from that location to where you installed R like this:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R home/andrespara/R-4.0.0/bin/R
sudo ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/Rscript home/andrespara/R-4.0.0/bin/Rscript
```

If any of the directories in that file path don't exist, you'll have to create them as well.